# Rendering variable to a page

Tags: javascript, html

Excuse the beginner level of this question, but could someone explain why this renders "Test" instead of foo?  As well as how to get it to render foo.

```
<script>
var test = foo;
</script>

<div>test</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might be better suited for a JavaScript tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Because test is not a variable inside the div. It's a string literal.

If you wish to render foo in there, then you'll have to do this...

```
<div id="divTest"></div>
<script>
    var test = 'foo';
    document.getElementById('divTest').innerHTML = test;
</script>
```

`test` above is a variable which has the text 'foo' assigned to it. I then set that variable's text inside the inner HTML of the div with id `divTest`.

I recommend you read some tutorials on HTML and JavaScript to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems:

- you're setting `test` equal to `foo`, when foo is `undefined`
- your HTML doesn't have access to any sort of JavaScript variables as is

If you want to make something like this work, try the following:

```
<div id="myInput"></div>
<script>
  var test = "test"
  var foo = test
  document.getElementById("myInput").innerHtml = foo
</script>
```